# Задать позицию для Tooltip. Jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть tooltip переопределеный через Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).tooltip({
        classes: {
            "ui-tooltip": "tooltip-style",
            "ui-tooltip-content": "tooltip-style-content",
        },
        position: { my: "left", at: "", target: 'mouse', },
        track: true,
    });
</script>

<style>
    .tooltip-style {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 3000;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .tooltip-style-content {
        font-family: Lato;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #4E4E4E;
    }
</style>
```

Все ка бы работает норм, стили кладуться тоже соответсвенно, только вот пытаюсь сделать так, что б тултип появлялся на месте курсора и дальше не трекился. Патался сделать `target: 'mouse',` или `track: true` но все не то. Игрался также с `position` и другими свойствами. Таргет не работает, трек просто следует с привязкою за курсором. Есть способ решения? Данное решение я делаю глобально для всего сайта, так что дергать по id не получиться.

Comment: что за тултип то, бутстрап? если глобально, то зачем привязывать стили через js, просто переопредлите их в css, лишний костыль вышел

Comment: Переопределял согласно документации. Тултип простой атрибут ''title"